# Store data into a static string ? I get an error: LNK2001 unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm sorry I saw the error has been posted many times, but they didn't seem similar.

Error: `public: static class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > Class::path" (?path@Class@@2V?$basic_string@DU?$char_t`

I was hoping I could run a function `getPath` that would take a file name and store it to a string. Somehow it doesn't work when using static?

```
class Class {
public:
    static std::string path;
    static void getPath();
};

void Class::getPath(PCWSTR FileName) {

    std::wcout << "FileName: " << FileName << std::endl;

    Class::path = "FileName";
}
```

Comment: You need to define `path`. What you have is a declaration.

Comment: See the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/12574407/434551 to the post marked as duplicate.

Comment: `static std::string path;` is a declaration, but not a definition. You need to add `std::string Class::path;` somewhere outside of, and after, the declaration of `Class` to actually define memory storage for `path`.

Comment: Thanks, @Remy Lebeau. Fixed my problem!